# Why does ILMerge delete security-related attributes?

Tags: ilmerge, partial-trust

At some time, ILMerge was changed so that it now deletes security-related attributes.

Questions:

- Why is this functionality implemented?
- And/or can it (safely) be removed from a private build of the tool (used to create a published assembly)?

The implementation in [the source code](https://github.com/Microsoft/ILMerge/blob/master/ILMerge/ILMerge.cs) is here, fwiw:

```cs
  #region Deal with [ComVisible] and security attributes
  var thisAssemblyIsComVisible = GetComVisibleSettingForAssembly(a);
  AttributeNode assemblyComVisibleAttribute = null;
  if (thisAssemblyIsComVisible != targetAssemblyIsComVisible) {
    InstanceInitializer ctor = SystemTypes.ComVisibleAttribute.GetConstructor(SystemTypes.Boolean);
    assemblyComVisibleAttribute = new AttributeNode(new MemberBinding(null, ctor), new ExpressionList(new Literal(thisAssemblyIsComVisible, SystemTypes.Boolean)));
  }
  for (int i = 0, n = a.Attributes == null ? 0 : a.Attributes.Count; i < n; i++) {
    AttributeNode aNode = a.Attributes[i];
    if (aNode == null) continue;
    if (aNode.Type == SystemTypes.ComVisibleAttribute) {
      a.Attributes[i] = null;
      continue;
    }
    if (aNode.Type == SystemTypes.SecurityCriticalAttribute
      || aNode.Type == SystemTypes.SecurityTransparentAttribute
      || aNode.Type == SystemTypes.AllowPartiallyTrustedCallersAttribute
      || aNode.Type.FullName.Equals("System.Security.SecurityRules")
      ) {
      WriteToLog("Assembly level attribute '{0}' from assembly '{1}' being deleted from target assembly",
        aNode.Type.FullName, a.Name);
      a.Attributes[i] = null;
      continue;
    }
  }
  #endregion
```

---

It causes problems for some people:

- It's [an open (currently unanswered) issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/ILMerge/issues/28)
- In [2012 someone was deliberately using](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/9c728d5f-c7b5-45cd-a779-dbbd071dc201/ilmerge-and-allowpartiallytrustedcallers?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious) an older version of ILMerge to avoid that problem (but I can't do that too, because I find that their old version of ILMerge won't run on WIndows 10).

I want to use ILMerge to build an assembly with the `AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers` attribute. I used to do that (with an older version of ILMerge) and don't know why I can't anymore.

I could presumably do it by not using ILMerge at all (i.e. by putting all the source code into one project, instead of building several projects to be merged), so I don't see what the harm is, i.e. why ILMerge will no longer do it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm now using [ILRepack](https://github.com/gluck/il-repack) instead, whose command-line is the same as ILMerge and which doesn't have this limitation.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19285256)

Comment: The essential pat is that you can avoid the problem described in the OP by using the ILRepack utility instead of ILMerge.

Comment: See also [Short answers and code-only answers](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1485/34757).